# C++ Templated function specialization with template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overloading, template-specialization

I have a templated function meant to work with STL containers. However, I'd like to specialize this function for a templated class. How might I go about doing this? I'm stuck on C++11.

Edit: Updated code example. It appears to work when `F` is a POD like `int`, but is broken in the below code example where `F` is a class.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class F>
class Temp {
  private:
    F f;

  public:
    Temp(F f) : f(f) {}
};

template <typename C, typename F>
struct MyClass {
  MyClass (const C& c, const F& f) { }
 
  operator C() const
    { return {}; }
};

// Base Template Function
template <typename C, typename F>
MyClass<C, F> operator| (const C & left, const F & right)
{
  std::cout << "Generic version" << std::endl;
  
  return MyClass<C, F>(left, right);
}

// Overload that I tried (ignored and used base template function instead)
template <typename C, typename F>
MyClass<C, F> operator| (const MyClass<C, F> & left, const F & right)
{
  std::cout << "MyClass overload" << std::endl;
 
  return MyClass<C, F>(C(left), right);
}

template <class F>
Temp<F> filter(F f) {
  return Temp<F>(f);
}

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> v0 = { 1, 2, 3 };
  auto m0 = v0
    | filter([] (int i) {return i > 0;});
  auto m1 = m0
    | filter([] (int i) {return i < 3;});
  return 0;
}
```

The above code example prints `Generic version` twice.

Comment: You can't partially specialize a template function. Are you sure the overload version is ignored?

Comment: Yes, the overload version is ignored. The result of the overloaded function is of type `MyClass<MyClass<C, F>, F>` instead of the desired `MyClass<C, F>`. 

Also, isn't the specialization that I provided a full specialization? @max66

Comment: No, your specialization is a partial specialization (you have template parameters: `C` and `F`).

Comment: @max66 Thank you for the correction. I mistakenly thought that the initial `template <>` would signify that the specialization is... specializing(?) both the `C` and `F` parameters; I guess I'll have to read more about template specializations. However, any idea about why the overload might be ignored here?

Comment: It seems to me that your overload specialization works perfectly. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't partially specialize a template function.

But your overload should works.

I've modified your `MyClass` class to make it compile but, in the following example, the overload version is in charge.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename C, typename F>
struct MyClass
 {
   template <typename ... Ts>
   MyClass (Ts const & ...) 
    { }

   operator C() const
    { return {}; }
 };


/* Base Template Function */
template <typename C, typename F>
MyClass<C, F> operator| (C const & left, F const & right)
 {
   std::cout << "Generic version" << std::endl;

   return MyClass<C, F>(left, right);
 }

/* Overload that I tried (ignored and used base template function instead) */
template <typename C, typename F>
MyClass<C, F> operator| (MyClass<C, F> const & left, F const & right)
 {
   std::cout << "MyClass overload" << std::endl;

   return MyClass<C, F>(C(left), right);
 }

int main ()
 { 
   MyClass<int, int> m0;

   auto x = m0 | 0;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(x), MyClass<int, int>>, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: It appears that this breaks when using lambas, which is what was happening for me before. I have edited the original question with a more extensive code example that demonstrates two calls to the generic function.

Comment: @minierolls - because are different `filter` types: every lambda is a specific type so `filter([] (int i) {return i > 0;});` and `filter([] (int i) {return i < 3;});` are different types; if you pass through `std::function` (`filter(std::function<bool(int)>{[] (int i) {return i > 0;}});` and `filter(std::function<bool(int)>{[] (int i) {return i < 3;}});`) the overload is called.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you so much!